# How to access NSObject class/instance variable from view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-method, class-variables

I want to pass a `NSString` value to a class method of a NSObject class: `+(void)loadTableData:(myCompletion) compblock;`. So I can only use a class variable `NSString *categoryID` for use in the class method. I declare it in the **.h** file trying to let it also be used for public access. But I tried many ways, and can only declare it like below. Other positions will give me warning.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void(^myCompletion)(NSArray *);
NSString *categoryID;

@interface ThirdVCLoadTable : NSObject
+ (void)loadTableData:(myCompletion) compblock;
@end
```

Then the problem is **I am still not able to access it in my view controller class**. The error message is always: **Property "categoryID" not found on object of type "ThirdVCLoadTable"**, no matter what I try in order to access the `NSString *categoryID`.

For example,

```
ThirdVCLoadTable *load = [[ThirdVCLoadTable alloc] init];
load.categoryID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row + 1];
```

Comment: You need declare property of string in .h file.@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *categoryID;

Comment: @Chenya Zhang
check my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not a property of the class. Try putting

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * categoryID;
```

below @interface

Comment: But I cannot directly use it in a **class method** in the .m file if it is a property.

Comment: That's not quite how you deal with class variable in Objective-C. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c#696024

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property in that class which you will call later from another view.

Suppose, in viewcontrollerA , in .h

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * StrName;

In viewcontrollerB, implement it like :

```
viewcontrollerA *vc = [[viewcontrollerA alloc]    initWithNib:@"viewcontrollerA" bundle:nil];
vc.StrName = @"XYZ";
[self pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Get more help from this :

[How to use NSString from NSObject class in multiple Classes (View Controllers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759342/how-to-use-nsstring-from-nsobject-class-in-multiple-classes-view-controllers)

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)

Comment: But I want to directly use the NSString in a **class method** in the NSObject's .m file as I described in the problem above.

Comment: You have two separate class/viewcontroller, right ? edit the question with more info. Paste codes from both class.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: 
  suppose   my ClassName is Info.

```
Info.h file

@interface Info : NSObject
typedef void(^myCompletion)(NSArray *);

@end
@interface ThirdVCLoadTable : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * categoryID;

+ (void)loadTableData:(myCompletion) compblock;
```

Info.m file

```
+ (void)loadTableData:(myCompletion) compblock {

}
```

if you want to access Class Method in viewControllers than
you can use like

```
ThirdVCLoadTable* load = [[ThirdVCLoadTable alloc] init];
load.categoryID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row + 1];
```